# Transpose of a int list list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I hope that this will be quite easy for some of you.
I found this solution in this forum:

```
let rec transpose list = match list with
| []             -> []
| []   :: xss    -> transpose xss
| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss)
```

This is a transposition of a list of lists and it works great.

Now I need the same this but instead of transposing an a' list list to a' list list to transpose int list list to int list list.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what polymorphism is about. The type `'a` can be any type, so the solution you found works just as well with `int list list`.

If you really want a function whose type is `int list list -> int list list`, you can always force it using type annotation :

```
let int_transpose : int list list -> int list list = transpose
```

But I don't see why you would.

Comment: Yeah, I know that 'a can be any type and works even better, but I have to make this function that way. Can you tell me or write the whole code where I can force this function that you wrote. Thank you!

Comment: @Marko Just add the single line I wrote (you can change `int_transpose` for any name, of course) to the definition of `transpose` you wrote. You can also directly annotate `transpose` if you want: `let rec transpose (list : int list list) : int list list = ...`

Comment: You can also just add a return type annotation to your function: `let rec transpose list : int list list = match ...` As cygin is telling you, this only changes the type, not the behavior of the function. So there's no real reason to do this other than perhaps for documentation. In some cases code goes faster with less polymorphism, but this isn't such a case because it just does list operations. Those are the same for all element types.